# Augmented Reality SDK for iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Does any one know any Augmented Reality SDK that supports both iOS and Android? What I need to do is detect classes of objects and based on the class type place information (text and images) on top of the real world object. I have seen a few libraries like Vuforia but they detect images and features not object classes.

Basically I want to implement something similar to Google Goggles landmark search feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Qualcomm's [Vuforia](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality) SDK. It looks promising there are a lot of apps on Google Play and iTunes App Store.

Comment: I already mentioned Vuforia in the question and the fact that it can't recognize object classes and is only used for target detection

Answer (score 0):

The ARToolkit is very popular for Android and iOS. May be you should give some further investigation.

Comment: Based on the description the library requires use of markers, so I dont think it can detect object classes. What I need is a bit more complicated, I need to detect for example any type of doors, windows, steps, etc... all based on object types not pre defined image markers.